# Reemplazar las expresiones de funcion con arrow function

Tags: javascript

Tengo que usar las arrow function para reemplazar este código

```
function ask(question, yes, no) {
  if (confirm(question)) yes()
  else no();
}

ask(
  "Do you agree?",
  function() {
    alert("You agreed.");
  },
  function() {
    alert("You canceled the execution.");
  }
);
```

No tengo ni idea de cómo reemplazarlo, he intentado poniendo => en you agreed pero no sé cómo hacerlo ni con los apuntes delante, ¿alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 1):

No es tan difícil, solo remplaza `function()` por `() =>` y elimina las llaves, porque se trata de una sola instrucción:

```js
function ask(question, yes, no) {
    if (confirm(question))
        yes()
    else
        no();
}
ask(
    "Do you agree?",
    () => alert("You agreed."),
    () => alert("You canceled the execution.")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría así:

```js
let ask = (question, yes, no) => confirm(question) ? yes() : no()

ask(
  "Do you agree?",
  () => alert("You agreed."),
  () => alert("You canceled the execution.")
);
```

Primeramente, puede haber variables de tipo función, así que lo primero sería crear una variable.

```
let ask = function(parametros){cuerpo}
```

Lo siguiente que hacemos es eliminar el keyword function y adaptar según el contenido tomando lo siguiente en cuenta:

No es necesario el return si de eso se trata toda tu función, por ejemplo

```
function saludo(aQuien){
  return "hola "+aQuien;
}
```

Se convierte en

```
let saludo = (aQuien)=> "hola" + aQuien;
```

Es compun ver ternarios para hacer que quede todo en una sola línea, como en tu caso

```
let ask = (question, yes, no) => confirm(question) ? yes() : no()
```

Si te resulta confuso puedes intentar indentarlo algo así:

```
let ask = (question, yes, no) => confirm(question) ?
                                    yes()
                                   :
                                    no()
```

Answer (score 0):

las funciones normales y las `arrow functions` pueden ser guardadas en variables, si lo deseas puedes acortar todo tu código en 2 lineas:

```js
const ask = (question, yes, no) => confirm(question) ? yes() : no();
ask("Do you agree??", ()=> alert("You agreed."), ()=> alert("You canceled the execution."));
```

Para crear una arrow function solo debes quitar la palabra reservada `function` y antes de `{` poner un igual y un `>` simulando una flecha:

```
//Arrow function anonima
()=>{
//Cuerpo de la arrow function
}
```

Para poder que la arrow function no sea anonima, es decir que podamos llamarla por un nombre por eso la guardamos en una variable:

```
const arrowFunc = ()=>{

}
arrowFunc();
```

Así es como creariamos una `arrow function`, la cual seria equivalente a:

```
function arrowFunc(){

}
arrowFunc();
```